# How to know what user logged in through nginx auth_basic from the proxy_pass app?

Tags: nginx, web-applications

I have an nginx webapp that uses auth_basic for authentication. How can I know from the app (proxy_pass) which user authenticated?

```
server {
    server_name <redacted>;
    client_max_body_size 32m;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7078;
        auth_basic "Authentication";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    # ...ssl config
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You'd need to check the `Authorization` HTTP header value. Check the example at the bottom of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) MDN documentation page to see what that header will contain when the basic auth is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ended up using:

```
proxy_set_header X-Auth-Username $remote_user;
```

and getting the username from the X-Auth-Username header.

Thanks to u/Fireye on Reddit